# Converting this C Code to Assembly to do Division shifting one bit at a time

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to convert this C Code to Assembly to do division without using the division sign. The C Code has been proven to work. I've finished converting the C Code to Assembly to the best of my ability. It will work correctly when dividing by 1 or when 0 is in the numerator, but will not work for division such as 5789217 / 8, 10 / 5, etc. The output for these is always that the quotient is 0 and the remainder is 0.

I tried making some minor tweaks here and there but ultimately im not sure where the assembly code is going wrong.

Here's the C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
 
    //first command line argument is the dividend
    long long dividend = atoll(argv[1]);
    //second command line argument is the divisor
    long long divisor = atoll(argv[2]);
    //we need the remainder 
    long long remainder = 0;
    //we need the quotient
    long long quotient = 0;

    if (divisor == 1) {
        quotient = dividend;
        remainder = 0;
    } else {
        //runs for 31 iterations as stated in the prompt 
        for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--){
            remainder <<= 1;
            remainder |= (dividend >> i) & 1;
            if (remainder >= divisor){
                remainder -= divisor;
                quotient |= 1 << i;
            }
        }
    }
 
    //print the results
    printf("%lld / %lld = %lld R %lld\n", dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder);
 
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is the UPDATED Assembly code:

```
.global _start

.data
dividend:
    .long 100
divisor:
    .long 100
quotient:
    .long 0
remainder:
    .long 0

.text
_start:
    movl quotient, %eax
    movl remainder, %edx
    movl divisor, %esi # previously ecx
    movl dividend, %ebx
    movl $31, %ecx # previously esi 
    # first if statement that checks if the divisor is 1
    cmpl $1, %esi
    jne for_start

    # divisor is 1, so quotient is dividend and remainder is 0
    movl %ebx, %eax
    xor %edx, %edx
    jmp done

for_start:
    cmpl $0, %ecx
    jle done

    # INSIDE FOR LOOP:

    shll $1, %edx        # shift remainder left
    movl %ebx, %edi      # copy dividend
    shrl %cl, %edi        # shift copy right
    and $1, %edi         # and 1 with the remainder
    orl %edi, %edx       # or the remainder and quotient CHECK THIS
    # start of if statement

    cmpl %esi, %edx       # compare the remainder and the divisor
    jle next_iter         # if remainder is less than divisor, skip subtraction

    sub %esi, %edx        # subtract divisor from remainder 
    movl $1, %edi
    shll %cl, %edi      # Shift quotient left by cl
    orl %edi, %eax     # Or quotient with 1

next_iter:
    decl %ecx             # decrement loop counter
    jns for_start

    # END OF FOR LOOP

done:

    nop
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. Anyway, the first issue is already at the `shrl $1, %ebx`. Notice that the C code does `>> i` not `>> 1`. Also, the C expression does not modify the `dividend`. Next, the C code applies the `& 1` to the `(dividend >> i)` but your asm code does `and $1, %edx` which is the `remainder`. Pay closer attention to details like this.

Comment: `and $1, %edx` is doing `remainder &= 1`.  That's not something the C source does, so your asm shouldn't do it.  Copy the dividend to another register and mask that.  (Or with more advanced tricks, instead of copying the low bit of the dividend, shift that bit out, and `adc %eax, %eax` to shift CF into the bottom of the quotient.  or `bt $0, %edx` / `adc %eax, %eax` to copy the bottom bit without shifting it out.)

Comment: @Jester: Well spotted about the dividend shift.  I was thinking it was a valid and good transformation to turn `dividend >> i` into shifting by 1 (strength reduction), but they actually have it backwards: the loop is from 31 down to 0.  It would work if they were *left* shifting the dividend and reading CF every time, like `add %ebx, %ebx` to set CF from its top bit, so `CF = (dividend >> i) & 1`, like if they did `bt %esi, %ebx`.  Then `adc %eax, %eax` to shift that bit into EAX.  But that transformation is something the comments should mention!!

Comment: BTW, this looks like a much improved re-ask of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239180/converting-c-to-assembly-integer-division-by-shifting-bits-one-at-a-time with an actual [mcve] this time.  The program doesn't output anything so they must already be using a debugger to check the result; as Jester says, use it to single-step.

Comment: Your C uses 64-bit signed integers (`long long`) despite using a bit-range of 31 to 0.  Your asm uses 32-bit unsigned integers.  In this case, 32-bit unsigned integers make a lot more sense for this algorithm; the C is basically wrong, and won't match `dividend / divisor` or `dividend % divisor` for negative inputs, or for large inputs.  (You can add those to the `printf` call to check the algorithm against C semantics.)

Comment: @Jester I changed the shrl $1, %ebx to shrl %cl, %ebx because I believe %cl will shift a variable amount? Not too sure about that part. You also mentioned that the C expression does not modify the dividend but that confuses me since in the C code the dividend is being shifted to the right by i.

Comment: Yes, you use %cl for variable shift but for that you actually need the count to be **in** `%cl` to start with. If you know C, then you know that `(dividend >> i)` leaves `dividend` unchanged, it produces the result in a temporary.

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried fixing the remainder |= (dividend >> i) & 1 part. I did shrl %cl, %ebx to bit shift the dividend to the right by i, then and $1, %ebx so the & is applied to the dividend, not the remainder. Then I put  or %edx, %ebx  to Or the remainder and dividend instead of the remainder and quotient.

Comment: @Jester How would I make the count to be in %cl to start with?

Comment: Most conveniently, change your register allocation so `i` is not in `esi` but `ecx`.

Comment: The obvious way would be to use `%ecx` as your loop counter instead of `%esi`.  (CL is the low byte of RCX)

Comment: @Jester but ecx is already a register for the divisor

Comment: `and $1, %ebx` is `dividend &= 1`.  Your C doesn't do that, it calculates a temporary value.  In asm you can do that with `mov` to another register, so you can shift and AND that copy of `dividend`. (Or like I said, use `bt` to get the temporary value into CF, but you need to understand the concept of calculating something without destroying the input.)

Comment: To use ECX for `i`, you'd obviously have to redo your register allocation to free it up.  Since you wouldn't be using ESI for anything else, you could load the divisor there.

Comment: @PeterCordes so you're saying i should do something like movl %ebx, %(temprorary register) which will move the dividend to the temporary register. Then I can shift it to the right by i, then & it with 1?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Example assembly code is in [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/joshudson/88570993c7863e4ba83af5fef61af2ad). (I had written it some months ago. Time to publish.) I'm certain if somebody stares at my algorithm long enough they'll find a way to tear it to shreds. I finally got one working on my own though.

Your algorithm is completely differently though.

The problem with your asm translation of your alrogithm is here:

```
    shll $1, %edx        # shift remainder left
    shrl $1, %ebx        # shift dividend right
    and $1, %edx         # and 1 with the remainder
```

After the first loop, `%edx` is either 0 or 1. After the second loop it must be 0.

It's like it wants to read

```
    shll $1, %edx        # shift remainder left
    movl %ebx, %edi      # copy dividend
    shrl %esi, %edi        # shift copy right
    and $1, %edi         # and 1 with the remainder
```

but that doesn't work because that shift instruction doesn't exist. Redo register allocation so that `i` is in `%cl` instead. (Put the divisor in `%esi` or something like that.)

```
    shll $1, %edx        # shift remainder left
    movl %ebx, %edi      # copy dividend
    shrl %cl, %edi        # shift copy right
    and $1, %edi         # and 1 with the remainder
```

Comment: `shrl $1, %ebx` isn't right; the C source doesn't modify either input variable (dividend or divisor).  (It's only doing 1 register width so it doesn't run out of registers needing to keep the originals *and* shifted copies.)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, too.  But as discussed in comments under the question, if you want to strength-reduce `dividend >> i` to shifting one bit at a time, it needs to go *left* since `i` starts at 31 and counts down to 0.  So `add %ebx, %ebx` or `shl $1, %ebx` to shift a bit into CF.  Or I guess `rol $1, %ebx` to rotate the top bit to the bottom, one bit at a time.  (Then copy the rotated dividend and mask to isolate that, before ORing into the remainder.)

Comment: Or `shld $1, %ebx, %edx` to shift one bit from the top of EBX into the bottom of EDX.  (And `shl $1, %ebx` to shift it out of EBX; `shld` only writes its destination.)  A chain of `shld` and a final `shl` is equivalent to your 16-bit `rcl` chains, but has better instruction-level parallelism since the dependency chain goes the other way, and we're not using CF.

Comment: Do I need to account for the or operation on the remainder as well?

Comment: There's no `|` operation on the remainder. If you mean the `|=`, writing back to the variable is the point.